# Get class name, then find element with an id that matches the class name

Tags: jquery, class, element

I am trying to perform a fairly simple task: get class name of one element and find and toggle the visibility of another element with an id that matches the class name. Both the class name and id are generated by php and are identical.

**HTML**

```
<div class="button">
  <a href="#" class="generatedName"></a>
</div>

<div id="generatedName">
  <p>Content</p>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
jQuery('.container').hide();

jQuery('.button a').click(function() {
    jQuery('div#' + this.class).toggle();
});
```

I have also tried getting the generated class and using a variable in place of `this.class`:

```
var button = jQuery('.button a').attr('class');
```

I have not had any luck. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in javascript(dom element), the `class` property is [`className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.className), so

```
jQuery('#' + this.className).toggle();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **[.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)** or **[.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)** to get the class name:

```
jQuery('#' + $(this).attr('class')).toggle();
```

However, your code will not work if your element have two or more classes, you should better apply `data-*` HTML5 attribute:

```
<div class="button">
    <a href="#" data-target="generatedName"></a>
</div>
```

then you can use `.data()` to retrieve `data-*` attribute:

```
jQuery('#' + $(this).data('target')).toggle();
```

*Side note*: `id` must be unique, you can simply use `#` instead of `div#`

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/985Qq/)**

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
$('.button a').click(function() {
    var $class = $(this).attr('class');
    $('div#' + $class).toggle();
});
```

## **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HGqkc/)**